# c# regex difference between .Match().Value and Match().ToString()

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code:

```
Match matcher = new Regex("[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+").Match("12/02/1994");

if (matcher.Success)
{
   string matchedString1 = matcher.Value;
   string matchedString2 = matcher.ToString();
}
```

In this case `matchedString1` and `matchedString2` contain the same value `"12/02/1994"`. Are `matcher.Value` and `matcher.ToString()` always returning the same results for any regular expression?

Comment: `ToString()` is often implemented to return something that would be helpful for use in debug window, concatenating objects etc.

Comment: yes, I decided to take matcher.Value. It "looks better" for me

Comment: Yes, the intent is clear by using `Value`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Match class derives from the Group class and this one derives from [Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.text.regularexpressions.capture%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class.

The Capture class overrides the ToString() method with this code:

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable, TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.Value;
}
```

so, yes, it is the same value.

Answer (score 2):

From *MSDN*;

[`Capture.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.value.aspx) Property;

> Gets the captured substring from the input string.

[`Capture.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.tostring.aspx) Method.

> Retrieves the captured substring from the input string by calling the
>   **Value** property.

Even when we look at *.NET Reflector*, we can see it `Capture` class override `ToString()` method like this;

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable, TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.Value;
}
```

So, yes. They have the same value.